# Exporting HTML table to Excel, file created but encoded HTML inside Excel sheet

Tags: excel, internet-explorer-8, export

I am exporting a HTML table to Excel file. I was using this for all other browsers:

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/>' + encodeURIComponent(tblHtml));
```

But for IE8, I have done following to make this export work:

1. jQuery post to send table html markup as string
2. Javascript that doing the post request:

   ```
   if (($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 8)) {
       $.ajax({
           url: '/exportdatatoexcel',
           data: {
               'tblToExport': tblHtml//encodeURIComponent(tblHtml)
               , 'tblID': id
           },
           type: 'POST',
           async: false,
           success: function (html) {
               //nothing to do
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               if (jqXHR.readyState != 0) {
                   alert('error occurred');
               }
           }
       });

       window.open("/exportdatatoexcelfilesavedialog", 'PopUp', 'width=500,height=300');
   }
   ```
3. Action that handles post request and window.open request (for opening file save dialog):

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateInput(false)]
   public ActionResult ExportDataToExcel(FormCollection form)
   {
       string tblToExport = form["tblToExport"], tblID = form["tblID"];

       Session["ExportTbl"] = tblToExport;

       ContentResult content = new ContentResult();
       return content;
   }
   [ValidateInput(false)]
   public ActionResult ExportDataToExcelFileSaveDialog()
   {
       Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; 
       Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=download.xls");
       Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

       object tblToExport = Session["ExportTbl"];
       return PartialView("_ExportToExcelForIE8", tblToExport.ToString());

   }
   ```

Now, when the file save dialog opens I can able to save the excel file but the excel file content is:

> %0d%0a%3cTABLE+dir%3dltr+id%3dtblCompAnalysis+class%3d%22clear+table+company-analysis-general%22+cellSpacing%3d0+cellPadding%3d0+width%3d%22100%25%22%3e%3cTBODY%3e%0d%0a%3cTR+class%3d%22labh+sort%22%3e%0d%0a%3cTD%3eCompany%3c%2fTD%3e%0d%0a%3cTD%3eMarket+Sector%3c%2fTD%3e%0d%0a%3cTD%3eArgaam+Sector+%3c%2fTD%3e%0d%0a%3cTD+class%3dcity%3eCity%3c%2fTD%3e%0d%0a%3cTD+class%3dtel%3ePhone%3c%2fTD%3e%0d%0a%3cTD+class%3dtel%3eFax%3c%2fTD%3e%0d%0a%3cTD%3eEmail%3c%2fTD%3e%0d%0a%3cTD%3eWebsite%3c%2fTD%3e%3c%2fTR%3e%0d%0a%3cTR%3e%0d%0a%3cTD%3e%3c

Comment: Were you able to get a solution to this? Nothing seems to be working in Ie..

Comment: yeh, we stopped supporting IE8. How's that!! ;)

Comment: They should stop releasing new versions of IE..